# Redirect from ListView to another ListView in Django 2.1

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling with one problem for some time. I would like to trough the website in following way.
Home page with links to categories -> When I go to categories then I would list all offers with this main categories. But also for given Category I would like to have posibility to filter those Category by subcategories. For now I'am fighting with step number one. Here is my code.

```
class HomeView(ListView):

    context_object_name = 'category'
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = 'accounts/home.html'

class GetOffersByCategory(ListView):
    model = Offer
    template_name = 'offer/offer_list.html'
    context_object_name="category"

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category,  name=self.kwargs['category'])
        return Offer.objects.filter(category=self.category)
```

And my Urls

```
path('', views.HomeView.as_view() ,name='home'),
path('offers/<category>',views.GetOffersByCategory.as_view(),name='offers'),
```

And my Models.

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    contact = models.IntegerField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='offer_images/',blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True,default="None")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('offers:offer_detail',args=[self.title, self.slug])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True ,related_name='children',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)   
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"        


    def __str__(self):                           
        full_path = [self.name]                  

        k = self.parent                          

        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.name)
            k = k.parent

        return ' -> '.join(full_path[::-1])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/offers/%s/" % self.slug
```

The main problem for me is to operate with urls in templates. Because I understand those simplier patterns like { url 'name' } but I don't know exacly how to create link like {% 'category:'MyCategoryFromDB'  %}. I don't want to going trough the for loop, because I know my categories. 
I hope that explanation of my problem is correct and it will be solved with your help :)

Comment: Can you share the models for category and offer please?

Comment: I assume `self.publisher` should be `self.category`? In your template, `{% url 'offers' category=category.name %}` will reverse the url correctly, assuming you are looping through your categories and have a `category` object.

Comment: and `context_object_name` shouldn't be "category" for the model `Offer`, it should be "offer_list" (would be confusing in your template since it's a list of offers). Idem for the `HomeView`, it should be `category_list`.

Comment: Well, after yours advices I've got error as follows " Reverse for 'offers' not found. '"

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this in `accounts/home.html`:

```
{% for category in object_list %}

    {% url 'offers' category.name %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: he's using the category name, so it should be `{% url 'offers' category=category.name %}`

Comment: So if I want to go to category 'Terraristic' then I should type  {% url 'offers' category=Terraristic %} ?  Actually I've got NoReverseMatch for offers :/